# Create extra instances of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a plugin called jQuery pusher (https://github.com/salvan13/jquery-pusher) to create some ajax-navigation on parts of a site, however this plugin can only be initialized once and I need to be able to apply it to new content loaded via ajax.

**My question:** could this be solved somehow via namespaces or some other way to create multiple instances of the same function that would not override/interfere with eachother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out for this particular plugin this is the solution: https://github.com/salvan13/jquery-pusher/issues/3

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you mean by the wording of your actual question, which I think is the source of your confusion.

It's true that plugin initialization can't be "deferred" in the same way that handlers can be deferred by jQuery, which applies the handler to a top-level element and filters the events from there.  Plugins need to be initialized directly on the element:

```
$('#someElement').pusher();
```

or group of matched elements:

```
$('.someElements').pusher();
```

So, for elements added to the DOM later, such as via AJAX, you'd need to explicitly initialize them after adding them:

```
$('#someContainingElement').load('ajaxcontent.html' function () {
    $('#someContainingElement .someElements').pusher();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Sorry if I was a bit unclear in stating my question. I've already done what you said, however the problem in this case is that once pusher runs on #someOtherElement it stops working on #someElement (it overrides itself when it runs a second time).
That is why I'm wondering if it can be solved via namespaces or similiar.

Comment: @jwaern: That's odd behavior, I wonder if the plugin author intended that for some reason.  If you initialize the plugin twice in a row on two elements (taking AJAX out of the picture entirely), do you still see that behavior?  Maybe the plugin requires that all matched elements be passed in a single initialization call?  In which case in the AJAX callback you'd just have to expand your selector to include all elements that need to be initialized.